# Using ROW_NUMBER() with a where clause to get the row number in the unfiltered table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider table `t`:

```
x  y
1  2
3  4
```

And the somewhat naive query

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY x ) row_num,
    x,
    y
FROM
    t
WHERE
    x = 3;
```

Which (understandably) outputs

```
row_num x  y
1       3  4
```

However, I want

```
row_num x  y
2       3  4
```

(`row_num` should be "calculated" over the unfiltered table, so before the `WHERE` clause is applied)

I tried

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t.x ) row_num,
    t1.x,
    t1.y 
FROM
    t, t as t1
WHERE
    t.x = t1.x AND t1.x = 3;
```

But I get the exact same output.

Will `ROW_NUMBER` always execute last, or is there a way to force it to execute first, then apply the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions being analytical, ad-hoc type of calculations  run on the current scope of the retrieved data. Unlike lexical order of most programming languages, SQL runs in logical order and not in the order commands are declared. Hence, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE` clauses are usually the *first* steps run in an SQL query. Therefore, once the data is retrieved, then window functions are calculated on that scope of data.

In fact SQLite's [window function docs](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) intimate this (emphasis added):

> A window function is an SQL function where the input values are taken from a "window" of one or more rows in the ***results set*** of a SELECT statement.

Instead of the self-join solution you arrived at (which uses the outmoded [implicit and not explicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/1422451)), you could have resolved your needs with CTE or subquery:

```sql
WITH sub AS (
  SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY x ) AS row_num
      , x
      , y
  FROM
      t
)

SELECT
     sub.row_num
     , sub.x
     , sub.y
FROM 
    sub
WHERE 
    sub.x = 3;
```

```sql
SELECT sub.row_num
       , sub.x
       , sub.y
FROM (
  SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY x ) AS row_num
      , x
      , y
  FROM
      t
  ) sub
WHERE 
    sub.x = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! Assuming this query will execute every time an API endpoint is hit, is one of the approaches you suggested preferable (performance-wise) over the other?

Comment: Consider benchmarking between the two within your environment. There is an ongoing debate of CTE vs subquery in performance. Hence, there is no rule of thumb. Though CTEs are arguably more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is 1 row from the table (provided that `x` is unique) then you can do it without selecting from a subquery or cte:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) row_num,
       x,
       y
FROM t
ORDER BY x = 3 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=33e7504381e1ea0282a7f31c9deccbec).
Results:

```
> row_num |  x |  y
> ------: | -: | -:
>       2 |  3 |  4
```

Comment: Cheeky! I love it.